# Fake Path File Upload and Retrieve

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, path

I am uploading some personal information to Mongo DB via Express Server(Node) and React. The problem is the files aren't uploaded to the 'uploads directory' on my server and on the DB i can see a fake path of the document with file name. How can I retrieve the file to display to user? I am able to retrieve the other personal information

Below are the codes
This is upload middleware

```
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, __dirname + '/uploads')
},

filename: function(req, file, cb){
    let ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
    cb(null, Date.now() + ext)
}
})

var upload = multer ({
storage: storage,
fileFilter: function(req, file, callback){
    if(
        file.mimetype == "image/png"  ||
           file.mimetype == "document/pdf"  ||
            file.mimetype == "document/docx"
    ){
        callback(null, true)
    } 
    else{
        console.log('Only png, pdf and Docx FILES ALLOWED')
        callback(null, false)
    }
    },
   limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2
   }
  })
```

This is Add Project controller

```
exports.add = (req, res, next) =>{

const { title, category, duration, durationSys, description, budget, addedBy, active,avatar} = req.body
let newProject = new Project({ 
    title, 
    category, 
    duration, 
    durationSys, 
    description,
    budget,
    addedBy,
    active,
    avatar
})
if(req.file){
    newProject.avatar = req.file.path
    }
newProject.save()
.then(response =>{
    res.json({
        message: 'Project added successfully'
    })
.catch(error =>{
    res.json({
        message: 'An error ocurred. Try again'
    })
})
})
};
```

This is the route

```
 router.post('/addproject', upload.single("avatar"),  add)
```

Frontend

```
  const Project= ({history}) => {
   const [values, setValues] = useState({
    title: '',
    category: '',
    duration:'',
    durationSys: '',
    description: 'Describe your project vividly here',
    avatar: '',
    active:'true',
    budget:'',
    addedBy: (isAuth().email),
    buttonText: 'Post'
   });


const { title, category, duration, durationSys,description,avatar, 
  active,addedBy, budget, buttonText } = values; 

   const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value } );
  };

   const clickSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, buttonText: 'Posting Project...' });
    console.log(avatar)
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/addproject`,
        data: { title, category, duration, durationSys, description, 
   avatar, active, addedBy, budget }
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('PROJECT ADD SUCCESS', response);
            setValues({ ...values, title: '', category: '',  duration: 
    '', durationSys: '',budget: '', description:'',avatar: '',  
   addedBy: '', buttonText: 'Success' });
            toast.success(response.data.message);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('PROJECT ADD ERROR', error.response.data);
            setValues({ ...values, buttonText: 'Try Again' });
            toast.error(error.response.data.error);
        });
    };
```

Comment: What is a "fake path"? Do you get an empty file in your directory or you get a string in your mongodb? Please provide some code and some more illustrative examples.

Comment: File not uploaded into my server directory. I instead get a fake path string location for the file

Comment: @thammada.ts see the codes below

Comment: @thammada.ts, I have edited and added the codes

Comment: So you don't have any files in your `uploads` folder? Does the folder exists?

Comment: @thammada.ts the folder exists on my server but nothing uploaded

Comment: this is the example fake path avatar
:
"C:\fakepath\AGREECE .pdf"

Comment: is the `uploads` folder part of `fakepath`?

Comment: no. It's not included in the link send to the database. Its also empty

Comment: I assume you are saving `file.originalname` to the database?

Comment: Yeah I wanna save it that way

Comment: `file.originalname` is the path on the users' machine, the real path has been masked by the browser as `"C:\fakepath\"`, you should try to `console.log(file.path)` to see the real destination of your file